# How do I get Synaptic's detailed description pane back?

Tags: synaptic

The [Synaptic package manager's](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) main window used to look similar to this (up to at least version 0.63):

[image]

Note the three panes.

However, in version 0.75, it looks like this:

[image]

So where did the detailed description pane (bottom right, first picture) go? And how do I reinstate it? This is really a make or break feature for me when browsing packages quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab this handle, and drag it up:

[image: instructions]

Comment: Genius. Thank you! I would never have spotted that.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution :
use `sudo apt-cache search apt |less` 
In UNIX world try to reduce to using graphical software.

Comment: I understand your point, but this doesn't help me. You only get single-line summaries with your command. Synaptic actually shows those too, as a column on the far right, although you can't see them in my screenshot. What I am interested in is easily scanning the paragraph of text below the summary line.

Comment: You can do it with `apt-cache show PKG_NAME`